# R Converting from datetime to date

Tags: r, date-difference

I have to do a difference between dates and return the number of days.
the format of the dates is as follows:

> 12/9/2011 12:00:00 AM

Does anyone know how to perform the difference without using lubridate?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can use `asPOSIXct` to convert to `DateTime`

```
v1 <- as.POSIXct("12/9/2011 12:00:00 AM", format = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

If we need only `Date`

```
as.Date(v1)
```

Comment: It' converting only a part of them:                                                  AEST" "2011-09-12 AEST" "2011-09-12 AEST" "2011-09-12 AEST" "2011-09-12 AEST"
 [9948] "2011-09-12 AEST" "2011-09-12 AEST" "2011-09-12 AEST" "2011-09-12 AEST" "2011-09-12 AEST" "2011-09-12 AEST" "2011-09-12 AEST"
 [9955] NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA                NA

Comment: @DarioFederici  In that case, the NA you showed may be of different format.

Comment: OK the solution is: v1 <- as.POSIXct(txns$Transaction_Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

Answer (score 4):

Convert datetime column in date format

```
df$DATETIME<-as.Date(df$DATETIME)
```